# Which class label is considered negative in sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I know that we can use a list to indicate the order:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], labels=[0,1]).ravel()
```

but the meaning of the elements of the matrix depends on two assumptions:

1. Whether rows or columns are considered as ACTUAL (or PREDICTED) labels.
2. Whether `0` or `1` is assumed to be the POSITIVE (or NEGATIVE) class.
   and none of them are directly mentioned in [the docstring](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).

---

This question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178590/scikit-learn-confusion-matrix), but I think here I am asking about the root of the confusion and not the confusion in its general term. The issue is not how to interpret the confusion-matrix, but how to set a specific class as positive or negative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scikit-learn confusion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178590/scikit-learn-confusion-matrix)

Comment: I noticed that before I post my question, but I think a more to-the-point question might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**
In binary classification, when using the argument `labels` ,

```
confusion_matrix([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], labels=[0,1]).ravel()
```

the class labels, `0`, and `1`, are considered as `Negative` and `Positive`, respectively. This is due to the order implied by the list, and not the alpha-numerical order.

---

**Verification:**
Consider an imbalance class labels like this: (using imbalance class to make the distinction easier)

```
>>> y_true = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
>>> y_pred = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]
>>> table = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labeels=[0,1]).reval()
```

this would give you a confusion table as follows:

```
>>> table
array([12,  1,  2,  1])
```

which corresponds to:

```
              Actual
        |   1   |   0  |
     ___________________
pred  1 |  TP=1 | FP=1 |
      0 |  FN=2 | TN=12|
```

where `FN=2` means that there were 2 cases where the model predicted the sample to be negative (i.e., `0`) but the actual label was positive (i.e., `1`), hence False Negative equals 2.

Similarly for `TN=12`, in 12 cases the model correctly predicted the negative class (`0`), hence True Negative equals 12.

This way everything adds up assuming that `sklearn` considers the first label (in `labels=[0,1]` as the negative class. Therefore, here, `0`, the first label, represents the negative class.